# Arrays of objects

Tags: javascript

Im a beginner in javascript and I have a trouble understanding why the console log doesnt returning me :
{ name: "Jim", Hungry: false },
{ name: "Nick", Hungry: false }.

The exercise consist in returning an array of object and adding element to each object.

The console log only returns {name: "Jim"}, and doesn't iterate and i have trouble understanding what im doing wrong.

So here's my code :

```js
const insert = (arr, obj) => {
  for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    return arr[i];
  }
  return arr;
};

console.log(
  insert([{ name: "Jim" }, { name: "Nick" }], {"Hungry": false})
);
```

Comment: The body of the for loop returns from the function on the first iteration.  I think the thing you want inside that loop is an assignment to the object at arr[i], something like `Object.assign(arr[i], obj)`.  Also, the loop should continue until `i<arr.length`

Comment: To actually "insert" `obj` in `arr[i]` you'll need to do something else than just return it, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
let items = []
const insert = (arr, obj) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     items.push(Object.assign(arr[i], obj));
  }
  return items
  
};

console.log(
  insert([{ name: "Jim" }, { name: "Nick" }], {"Hungry": false})
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [{ name: "Jim" }, { name: "Nick" }];
const obj = { Hungry: false };
const hunger = obj.Hungry;

console.log("The key of that object is "+"  "+Object.keys(obj)[0])
const ew = arr.map((item) => {
  item[Object.keys(obj)[0]] = hunger;
  return item
});

console.log("The updated array"+JSON.stringify(ew));
```

This is a static solution for this question. If the number of keys in that object increases, this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, returning within a `for` loop exits the loop and the outer context (your function), returning only the value following `return`.

What you want to do is [*map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array to a new one with each item merged with `obj`. This is particularly easy with [*spread syntax*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals).

For example

```js
const insert = (arr, obj) => arr.map((item) => ({ ...item, ...obj }))

console.log(
  insert([{ name: "Jim" }, { name: "Nick" }], {"Hungry": false})
);
```